Issues with reading files off of the filesystem in vercel
So, I've been making a website, which has a "blog" in it, consisting of a few markdown files, which I just read off of the file system. Said read works perfectly with 0 errors everywhere on anything, except when i deploy on vercel. There is just returns "No such file or directory".
The whole project is written in NextJS(14.2.4), using app router. For the parsing of markdown files, I use the following function:
const path = join(process.cwd(), "/public/Posts");

const imgPath = join(process.cwd() + "/public/Images/PostImages");

export default async function PostMapper() {
  const files = readdirSync(path);
  const image = readdirSync(imgPath);
  const posts = files.map((fileName) => {
    const slug = fileName.replace(".md", "");
    const readFile = readFileSync(`${path}/${fileName}`);
    const { data: frontmatter, content: content } = matter(readFile);
    return {
      slug,
      frontmatter,
      content,
      image,
    };
  });

  return posts;

Again, I wanna emphasize that said function just works everywhere, except when deployed on vercel and that when their "directory listing" feature is enabled, the folder with the markdown files is there, which leaves me even more confused... Any help would be greatly appreciated!
I've tried fixing this bug for a while now with nothing concrete, as it's a bit hard to troubleshoot a problem that only happens when deployed on vercel.
I've tried changing  the path variable, moving the folder around and changing how the function reads files to no avail...

Vercel's Directory Listing is meant to be consumed with http/https, it's just a kind of security feature to allow client to access the file in the specific directory in you app.
By deploying your app on Vercel, you loose the access to filesystem as it is not a long life run server even if it's a nodejs functions.
It's better if you can read the markdown file by fetching it from you public directory or external CDN and parse the content text inside, which will work anywhere.

So you're saying that my entire approach is wrong....

I won't say you're wrong with your approach, It'll be okay as you said with server that always run. but for serverless approach, it's not the good architecture, at least for the part that needs filesystem handling

To add more context, the process.cwd() might returns different path every time the route/server action gets called, it boots up a partial nodejs env, and die when the task is done. you may check on your vercel logs to see it, it shows how much time the actions is running.
